# Can I get likes and comments for a searched user with Instagram api on localhost without having my app reviewd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, instagram-api

I was trying to do the project where u user types a username in a search field and it gets the user profile with the number of likes per post and comments. The app is in React and NextJS. To do that I upgraded my Instagram account first to creator then to business professional, next I created an app in https://developers.facebook.com/, and in the allowed domains and redirect I entered my website and localhost. This is the Login function

```
 FB.login(
              (response) => {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                  console.log("Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ");
                  const token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                  setAccessToken(token);
                  const userId = response.authResponse.userID;
                } else {
                  console.log(
                    "User canceled login or did not fully authorize."
                  );
                }
              },
              { scope: "email,public_profile" }
            );
```

And here is my first question, does a user have to do that? Can't I connect my account to do this search, I have tried to implement this function in useEffect found in the docs that the browser would block it if this is not in the handler.

As you can see I query for the scope email and public profile here, to query for media or comments in graph Api I need permissions for instagram_basic, pages_read_engagement and pages_show_list but when I set the scope to these, on Click the popup opens with the message "Sorry something went wrong..." and I don't know if this is the matter of permissions or something else. And in the docs they say

Apps may ask for the following two permissions from any person without submitting for review by Facebook:

public profile
email

Is it possible to get the number of likes and comments without submitting the app for review? What do I need to do to be able to request instagram basic and pages show list credentials?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure how you would achieve that the way you do right now, but you can use something like selenium to open a browser window on the user you want and then you can scrape the data you need